# Zend_Form not submitting

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

I built a custom Zend_Form "myForm" and I passed it to my view with:

```
$this->view->form=new myForm();
```

**Problem:** form is not submitting (page doesn't reload/refresh).I thought something was wrong with the "form" tags,but I copyied the bottom code in another page (that is not a Zend environment) and is working.This is the source code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">

<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" class=""> 
<textarea name="text" id="text" class=""></textarea>
<input type="text" name="allegati" id="allegati" value="" class="">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="media[]"></span>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" class="">
</form>
```

**SOLVED:** As some of you guys suggested javascript is giving problems: 
I had a js script overriding with:

```
$('form').submit();
```

Thanks

Luca

Comment: your form has no action. it doesn't know where to submit to.

Comment: it doesnt matter.Page should load..and it doesnt

Comment: @kjy112 an empty `action` attribute will submit the form to the current URL.

Comment: Is there any javascript on the page that overrides the `onsubmit` even?

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is since it looks like a form that should by all means work. Try removing the span that that doesn't seem to belong there? Doubt it'll help though... Try disabling JS? Try another browser?

Comment: yeah i'm doublechecking Js side if overrides i'll post updates as soon as Im done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form submitting issues are 99% related to javascript conflicts with the 'form' element or with a wrong defined 'form' tag.
Always check those above when encountering problems.

P.s. for the remaining 1% feel free to ask at Stack!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion - try to rename your submit button to something but not "submit" (i.e name="mysubmitbutton").
I think the problem could be with expandos: http://ejohn.org/blog/deadly-expandos/. By default, a form element has a `submit` function. But, if you call any field inside your form with the name "submit" (like you do in your example), the form.submit will point to your input element and you'll not be able to submit your form.